# Windows 10 - Get first logon and last logoff for each day for date range

Tags: windows-10, powershell, login, date, event-viewer

I'm looking to see if there's a way to parse `eventvwr` to get the first logon and last logoff on a particular PC for each date in a range. I don't need to get any particular user... just first and last event.

Possibly get the first and last `Winlogon` event under `Windows Logs > System` for each distinct date?

Any information or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Exactly what *sort* of logon are you after? You do realize a domain workstation could have hundreds of logon sessions established per day, even if a human only logs in/out a few times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried?
What resources have you looked at?
Show us your code?
Describe what is not working / port the errors.
Have you looked at the examples provided in the PowerShell built-in cmdlets for working with event logs.

```
Get-Command -Name '*winEvent*'

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                                                                 
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                                                                 
Cmdlet          Get-WinEvent                                       3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics                                                       
Cmdlet          New-WinEvent                                       3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics  


Get-Command -Name '*event*log*'

-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                                                                 
Cmdlet          Clear-EventLog                                     3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                                                        
Cmdlet          Get-EventLog                                       3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                                                        
Cmdlet          Limit-EventLog                                     3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                                                        
Cmdlet          New-EventLog                                       3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                                                        
Cmdlet          New-PefEventLogTrigger                             1.1.0.0    PEF                                                                                    
Cmdlet          Remove-EventLog                                    3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                                                        
Cmdlet          Show-EventLog                                      3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management                                                        
Cmdlet          Write-EventLog                                     3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     


# Get parameters, examples, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function

(Get-Command -Name Get-EventLog).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-EventLog -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-EventLog -Full
Get-help -Name Get-EventLog -Online
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/24/use-powershell-cmdlet-to-filter-event-log-for-easy-parsing

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I needed to get started.  I was able to use `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='system'; id=7001; StartTime="2/11/11"}` for logon and `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='system'; id=7002; StartTime="2/11/11"}` for logoffs and do the rest in Excel. I apologize that I was vague.  This is one of the few times I've used PowerShell.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. Welcome to world of PowerShell.